# WordPress - Как вернуть пост по ссылке URL

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть пост по ссылке https://домен/oborudovanie/

В WP есть функция get_post() - но ей нужно передавать ID. Есть ли похожая функция, которой можно передать ссылку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна функция url_to_postid

https://wp-kama.ru/function/url_to_postid